How to export data from Binance spot chart?
I need to export data from Binance spot chart: https://www.binance.com/en/trade/BTC_USDT?type=spot.
I need data like this:

High price
Low price
Open price
Close price

I also need MACD indicators:

9-day
12-day
26-day

Numbers are needed for each week or any other time frame I set. I will also need to export other data like RSI, MFI in the future. And also for other cryptocurrency pairs, not only BTC-USDT. So the solution needs to be scalable.
I do one research, so need this data. I tried this solution: https://www.binance.com/en/support/faq/how-to-download-historical-market-data-on-binance-5810ae42176b4770b880ce1f14932262 - downloaded the data, but it was not what I need.
I need the data in CSV format.
How can I do this in the fastest and easiest way?
Do I have to write a new program or is there already a solution?


https://github.com/ltftf/binance-historical-data

Binance offers two methods to access the historical data: through their API in JSON format or this webpage in CSV format. It's impossible to quickly get historical data for data types like trades and aggTrades with the first method, and it would still require some manual labor to fetch a lot of files with the second method.
This library allows to collect data in CSV format for any date range, any number of symbols and intervals (if present) with a single command.

Untried.

Thank you. It's working. But the utility doesn't allow to export MACD and other indicators data. Of course it can be calculated manually, but I would like to export it to be the same as on Binance.

I'll mark your solution as an answer. And give a little clarification.
This script downloads all necessary data, but some dates may be missing, you need to check this additionally with formulas.
I found it easier to calculate MACD by hand, it is quite easy in Excel.
